# Algolia/Autocomplete : give handler to onSelect

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, autocomplete, algolia

I'm setting up multiple [Algolia/autocomplete](https://www.algolia.com/doc/ui-libraries/autocomplete/api-reference/autocomplete-js/autocomplete/) fields in a ES6 class, I would like to extract the `onSelect` handler, so I could use some data_attributes in the HTML node, But I can't figure out how to do it.

Here is my JS class:

```js
import { autocomplete } from '@algolia/autocomplete-js';

export default class AutocompleteSetUp {

  init() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.entity-autocomplete').forEach(elem => {
      this.autocomplete_elem_setup(elem);
    });
  }

  autocompleteSelectionHandler(some params) {
    console.log('I NEED TO PERFORM SOME ACTIONS HERE');
  }

  autocomplete_elem_setup(htmlNode) {

    autocomplete({
      container: htmlNode,

      // DYNAMIC SEARCH
      getSources({ query }) {
        return fetch(
          `/artists.json?query=${query}`
        )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          return [
            {
              sourceId: `artists`,
              getItems() {
                return data;
              },
              getItemInputValue({ item }) {
                return item.name;
              },
              // ...
              templates: {
                header() {
                  return 'Suggestions';
                },
                item({ item }) {
                  return `Artist: ${item.name}`;
                },
                footer() {
                  return 'Powered by Algolia Autocomplete';
                },
              },

              onSelect({ item }) {
                console.log(item);
                console.log('container:', htmlNode );
                console.log('source:', source );
                // Here I'm able to perform some actions
                // But I need to extract this code in another function in the class:
                // How can I call autocompleteSelectionHandler ?

                // This doesn't work:
                this.autocompleteSelectionHandler(some_params);

              },


            },
          ];
        });
      },
    });
  }
}
```

To be honest, I would love to also exact other handlers for "clean_codeness" (like `item` in `templates`), but I need to call several methods in `onSelect` so I really have no choice.